Military sci-fi about genetically modified soldiers
Read a book a long time ago, trying to find it again. It's about humans, in the future, who figured out how to genetically modify soldiers to always revert back to the physical state they were in when they had the procedure. Almost like reversing time. They undertook the process when at their strongest, well fed, not hungry or thirsty or anything, so perfect in every way. They would then always return to that state over a short time. The main character is about to go through this when something happens, attacked I think, and he is forced to do it while somewhat hungry, tired, and thirsty. There were also special suits of armor that the soldiers wore, that was your typical futuristic power armor type thing. It is old, but when I read it, it was newly published, I think. Not positive when I read it, 5-6 years ago maybe.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  If it was an e-book, is it not still in your library?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters or places they visited?

I use a subscription service that lets me pay monthly to have a large amount of ebooks free for me to borrow and return, instead of buying them

Sounds like the Intergalactic Wizard Scout Chronicles, a series of 12 novels published 2015-2021 so feasible that you read at least some of them six years ago.
The Wizard Scouts are elite troops, highly trained, with access to 'power reserves' that they can use to heal themselves and to perform other actions (scanning, attacking others, healing, etc) - most specialised in a limited number of abilities.
The protagonist, Richard 'Rick' Shepard has an aptitude for all aspects of power use.
The self heal was based on a 'DNA baseline' - the power automatically reset the body to its condition when the baseline was set. As such it was meant to be taken when they were at the peak of training and well rested. Rick is in fair condition but not 100% and is then kept up all night before his baseline so is tired and hungry when his is set.
Wizard Scouts have power assisted armour which includes a 'battle helmet' with an embedded computer which can assist or completely control the suit, and with which they communicate telepathically.
By the end of the series it includes time travel, interdimensional travel, elves, dwarves, gnomes, angels, and at least one visit to hell.

This is it! Thank you very much, it's been nagging me for days haha

@AvariciousReader In that case, please click on the check mark under the voting buttons to verify the answer is correct.
